# displaying results horizontally in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how can achieve to display the result in horizontal manner?
   as show in my database, i have 3 fields.  subject, result, period.
   im planning to just create period1, period2, period3, period4 field
   to save value for each period, but i dont think its not advisable.

```
sample database:  
subject    |  result    |    period   |
--------------------------------------  
 eng       |   100      |      1      |  
 lit       |   95       |      1      |  
 eng       |   95       |      2      |  
 lit       |   86       |      2      |  
 eng       |   92       |      3      |  
 lit       |   88       |      3      |     


subject  |  period1  |  period2  |  period3  |  period4  |  
-----------------------------------------------------------  
eng      |    100    |   95      |     92    |           |  
lit      |    95     |   86      |     88    |           |  

hope you can help mo guys. thank you in advance.
```

Comment: No, its not advisable, unless you are absolutely certain you wont ever need more than 4 periods. This seems like pointless de-normalization - why do you want to do it?

Comment: Do want a view (SQL) or table (Html)?

Comment: i only need 4 periods, can you show me how to do it both sql and html?

Comment: You can either do a simple loop in PHP, or an agonizing pivot in MySQL. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and straightforward solution:

```
select 
    aggr.subject, 
    max(aggr.period1), 
    max(aggr.period2), 
    max(aggr.period3), 
    max(aggr.period4) 
from (
    select 
        subject as subject, 
        result as period1, 
        0 as period2, 
        0 as period3, 
        0 as period4 
    from test 
    where period = 1 
    union 
    select 
        subject, 
        0, 
        result, 
        0, 
        0 
    from test 
    where period = 2 
    union 
    select 
        subject, 
        0, 
        0, 
        result, 
        0 
    from test 
    where period = 3 
    union 
    select 
        subject, 
        0, 
        0, 
        0, 
        result 
    from test 
    where period = 4
) aggr group by aggr.subject;
```